# How to create build file for Nant of .Net project

Tags: nant

I have created build files of c# solution(.sln) files as well as the .cs file, but if i want to create a build file of only one project out of more than one project in a solution, i gets error some of those are like escape sequence character "\" etc.

I am including the project file as `<include name="projectname.csproj" />`

Comment: I have a solution file and it has 4 project, now i have to automate the build process with NAnt please give some example.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to another answer that contains a sample.

Answer (score 2):

NAnt does not use the project files directly. Either use the csc task or the msbuild to build a solution. You can read more in the documentation abou these tasks.

**UPDATE:**
You can read the latest documentation at http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/

**UPDATE 2:**
Here's a link to an answer ashowing how you can achieve this by calling msbuild: [<msbuild> task or msbuild.exe with NAnt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195389/msbuild-task-or-msbuild-exe-with-nant)