# VS2010 devenv command from CC/NAnt fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net, nant

We automate builds with CruiseControl / NAnt and it has always worked with VS2005.

We recently upgraded to VS2010 and are now seeing several projects give a "Rebuild All" message, but nothing else:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: EventSetup, Configuration: BuildTWinWithPortalSvc Win32 ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: TempFileManager, Configuration: BuildTWinWithPortalSvc Win32 ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Mont, Configuration: BuildTWinWithPortalSvc Win32 ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: NOTATION, Configuration: BuildTWinWithPortalSvc Win32 ------
```

This happens for 100+ projects.  Building from IDE or by calling devenv from cmd works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can build using MSBuild directly (see [<msbuild> task or msbuild.exe with NAnt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195389/msbuild-task-or-msbuild-exe-with-nant/1202121#1202121)). Using the `<devenv>` command requires Visual Studio to be installed on your build server.

The method has worked for me for projects built in VS 2008, 2010, and 2012 and across all of the .NET versions since you are plugging directly into MSBuild (which is what Visual Studio calls too).

Comment: We do have VS installed on our build machine.  The problem with MSBuild is we use VS setup projects (.vdproj)